Weird output of mount/findmnt command from inside a chroot jail
On my Linux system I entered a chroot jail using chroot(1) and then mounted a procfs instance on /proc from there.
Now if I do cat /etc/mtab from inside the chroot jail, it shows the full list of mountpoints as from outside the chroot jail. According to mount(8) it should parse /etc/mtab (on my system /etc/mtab is actually a symlink to /proc/mounts).
Neverthless mount command from the inside only lists the procfs instance mounted on /proc (actually /carlo/carlo-ubuntu/proc from outside the chroot jail).
[host:~]$ chroot /carlo/carlo-ubuntu /bin/bash
root@host:/#
root@host:/# ls -la /etc/mtab       
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 12 Nov 20 11:00 /etc/mtab -> /proc/mounts
root@host:/#
root@host:/# ps
Error, do this: mount -t proc proc /proc
root@host:/# mount -t proc proc /proc
root@host:/# mount
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
root@host:/# 
root@host:/# findmnt 
TARGET
      SOURCE
           FSTYPE OPTIONS
/proc proc proc   rw,relatime
root@host:/# 
root@host:/# cat /etc/mtab 
rootfs / rootfs rw,seclabel 0 0
/proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
none /dev devtmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=9088036k,nr_inodes=2272009,mode=755 0 0
/dev/mapper/panini_vol_grp-host_lv0 / ext4 rw,seclabel,noatime,discard,i_version,data=ordered 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,relatime 0 0
run /run tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /var/volatile tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /media/ram tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=65536k 0 0
none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
root@host:/#

Is the above an expected behavior ? Thanks.
